# How to find the name or type of a contract in Solidity

Tags: solidity

Suppose I have solidity contracts that inherit from another contract:

```
contract A {}
contract B is A {}
contract C is A {}
```

If I make an array of A objects and populate them with it's subclasses:

```
A[] memory examples = new A[3];
examples[0] = new A();
examples[1] = new B();
examples[2] = new C();
```

How can I dynamically determine which subtype of A is being referenced, if I were to loop over `examples`? I'm looking for an equivalent of JavaScript's `typeof` operator so that I might do:

```
if(typeof(example) == A) {
  // Do stuff
} else {
  // Do something else
}
```

I'd settle for even the name of the constructor. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the bytecode of the contract, you could possibly use solidity assembly to read the code in storage at the contract, and parse through code searching for recognizable segments of bytecode, although this is in absolutely no way safe, or even guranteed to work.

As far as I know what you're trying to don't work. You used to be able to convert contract types to byte type but this was phased out in a recently released version of the solidity compiler. If you need to identify the type of a contract, or name of the contract, why not embed a public variable that's descriptive of the contract, say a hash of the bytecode? You could then create a getter for these contracts that you can use. Granted this will only work for contracts you can deploy yourself and wouldn't work for contracts other people have written.

AFAIK the following EIP is attempting to create a standard for something like this:
https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/165

Answer (score 0):

Solidity doesn't provide the `typeof` to be used to determine the type of a certain contract. But with a bit of code you can create something that will help you to do so:

```
library Constants {
    enum ClassTypes { A, B, C }
}

contract A {
    function getType() public pure returns(Constants.ClassTypes) {
        return Constants.ClassTypes.A;
    }
}
contract B is A {
    function getType() public pure returns(Constants.ClassTypes) {
        return Constants.ClassTypes.B;
    }
}
contract C is A {
    function getType() public pure returns(Constants.ClassTypes) {
        return Constants.ClassTypes.C;
    }
}

contract D {
    function test() public returns(string) {
        A[] memory examples = new A[](3);
        examples[0] = new A();
        examples[1] = new B();
        examples[2] = new C();

        if(examples[0].getType() == Constants.ClassTypes.A) {
            // is A
        }
    }
}
```